# loop through all form elements with javascript give an error in the console

Tags: javascript, html, forms, for-loop

I created only 1 form with some input fields in it, so this should be `document.forms[0]`. Now looping through the form elements, it gives me some results, which is fine, but after that the loop wants to carry on instead of stopping at the 1 and only form in the page. Obviously, it can't find any other form on the page other than the single one, so it give a console error...

Can someone please tell me why the loop doesn't wanna stop at the only form on the page?

Please check this jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sxfmN/

Many  Thanks

Comment: the `max` var is shared between the loops, the inner for loop increments it to a value meaningless to the outer for loop

Comment: Wow... I must have been asleep while coding. Thanks @Alex K. It works now.